# How to define a jQuery function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write an jquery function because otherwise I have to write some code over and over.

Here is wat the function was first:

```
 $(".checkbox-car").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('checked-car')
        });

         $(".checkbox-bus").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('checked-bus')
        });
```

And this is what I tried to do with my own function:

```
    $.fn.checkedFunction = function(Clicked, Checked){
        $(this).click(function(){
            console.log('check');
            $(Clicked).toggleClass(Checked);
        });
    }

    $('.checkbox-car').checkedFunction('.checkbox-car','.checked-car');
```

But I get the error that the checkedFunction is not defined.

What am I doing wrong here can someone help me out?

Comment: Your code seems almost entirely redundant - you're just wrapping the existing `.toggleClass()` method and adding no extra functionality.

Comment: You should have a look at how to [bind functions to the jQuery.fn prototype](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error that  checkedFunction isn't defined because it isn't. `checkedFunction` is a property defined in`$.fn` object.

To use the function you created, you should do 
`$(".some-element").checkedFunction(...args)`.

More over, you should read the jQuery docs.

Comment: You should remove the Clicked param. "this" is the jQuery element selected.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this:

```
    $.fn.checkedFunction = function(Clicked, Checked){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(Clicked).toggleClass(Checked);
        });
    }

    $('.checkbox-car').checkedFunction('.checkbox-car','checked-car');
    $('.checkbox-bus').checkedFunction('.checkbox-bus','checked-bus');
```

remove the dot before the second checked- class